# why there is two pip are installed in my linuxmint?

Tags: linux, pip

[2 pip are installed one is v 9 and other is v 19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D989W.jpg)

how to update the pip to the latest version 19?
I m unable to download some packages due to this version conflict.
and I want only one latest pip version should be instaled, and it will be used in all the packages.

Comment: also what is pip3 ?

Comment: `pip3` is the package manager for python v3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to upgrade pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41172757/unable-to-upgrade-pip)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two different versions of python and pip installed. This is common.

`/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip` was most likely installed by the operating system, and allows you to `sudo pip install` Python 2.7 packages.

`/home/manish/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip` is in your home folder, which means you shouldn't have to elevate your user privileges to `pip install` a package. This is for Python 3.5.

Managing Python versions and dependencies can be massively confusing, especially if you're just trying to follow along with a tutorial.

The best tool I can recommend to make sense of this is `pyenv`. It lets you install any version of python in your home folder, and allows you to switch between on a per-project (folder) basis by creating a `.python-version` file. [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#simple-python-version-management-pyenv).

Comment: I upgraded my /home/manish/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip by using the command  **pip install --user mercurial** command so now i have latest vesrion of pip in both.but now i got confused, which pip should i use for the blockchain tut with anacondo python3 based?

Comment: The `which` command can be helpful to determine which executable you are running. `which pip` will tell you the location of pip that gets executed. e.g. - path contains `../python2.7/..` or `../python3.5/..`

Comment: u didn't get my question. what i am saying is, i need to install flask (python package) which i have to use in anaconda/spyder. so where should i now install the flask?

Comment: `pip` should handle the installation location for you. First, we need to figure out which `pip` is being referenced. Paste the output of `which pip` in a comment, here.

Comment: manish@manish-VPCEH28FN ~ $ which pip
/home/manish/.local/bin/pip

Comment: `pip install --user flask`